# Symfony2 cache clear bad with sh

Tags: symfony, sh, runtimeexception

clearing symfony2 cache on shared server with:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Gives me red box with error:

```
[RuntimeException]
sh:  :  command not found
```

It used to work before on the server, not sure what changed and how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was with my parameters.ini. I'm not sure exactly what as I changed a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to:

1. Check that `app/console` has execute permissions
2. Check that `php` is aliased to right `php5-cli` or whatever you use

Comment: I've set the permissions on console and ensured I'm using the right php; this was not the problem unfortunately. Thanks for answering.